# Starting applications on bootup

Tags: startup, startup-applications

I have been searching for a while for a method that starts applications on boot.

- `rc.local`
- Startup Applications in Ubuntu.

Is Startup Applications available only on Ubuntu, or does it have versions in other distributions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all distibutions that are based on Ubuntu have "Startup Applications" option. I'm not sure about distors that are not based on Ubuntu.

I can confirm that 
"Elementary OS, Zorin OS, Linux Mint" have it.

Comment: Lubuntu has this feature as well although the interface is different.  Strictly speaking though, Startup Applications starts applications on login, not on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Startup Applications, as far as I know, adds a `.desktop` file to `/etc/xdg/autostart/` directory. This directory is not exclusive to Ubuntu.  I run Fedora 20 on my other laptop, and it's the same method. Another way is to place a `.desktop` file into your `~/.config/autostart/` directory. Again , this is not exclusive to Ubuntu.

In both cases, though, the scripts/programs open on particular user login.

As for rc.local, it's part of System V init tools, and it can be specified to run on boot, specific runlevel, reboot, or shutdown. You can learn about it slightly more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/5042/295286) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59945)