# Two different ways of starting a service. Why?

Tags: 14.04, init.d

What are the differences between the two following ways or starting something, first being:

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

And second:

```
/usr/bin/redis-server
```

I've never really fully understood why which is preferred over the other.

Comment: Might be related:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/5039/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-init-and-etc-init-d

Comment: How do you stop the service?

Comment: @muru Normally I have to get the process id via `ps aux | grep redis-server` and the do a kill `kill -9 <PID>`. Which is annoying.

Comment: @KarlMorrison there you have it. The init script is supposed to take care of that for you. It has a `stop` command, and other related commands like `status`, `restart`, etc., a standardised set so that **you** don't have to figure out how to do those things.

Comment: @muru I guess I'm learning new things everyday :) What about `service redis-server start/stop`? Those I do know that I need to get the pid and kill.

Comment: @KarlMorrison you shouldn't have to. There are different init systems (i.e., systems to manage services and boot), and naturally they all have different command sets. The `service` command is a wrapper script which calls the correct set of commands depending on the system. In this case, the same `init.d` script you mentioned - you shouldn't have to kill manually. If you do, it's a bug and should be reported.

Comment: @muru I guess I am doing something incorrect on my server setup, I will look into it. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/q/2075/158442

Comment: Also, do lookup the `pkill` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever goes into `/etc/init.d` is a script that starts a service  and may define appropriate level where the script runs - single user mod, multiuser, shutdown; it's not the service itself.

Whatever goes into `/usr/bin` is the actual server, it is the executable file.

The analogy from windows world would be `.exe` files vs scheduled services that call those `.exe` files